# Is there a way to resize a split such that it exactly fits its content (plus/minus N lines of buffer-space)?

Tags: key-bindings, split, window-management

I often find myself doing something like this with a tiny header file with only a few lines:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>
- <kbd>50</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>
- <kbd>50</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>
- <kbd>30</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>
- <kbd>10</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>

… or similar, to slowly "zero in" my window-height on the height of the actual file's contents.

Ideally, I'd like the sort of “inverse” of `'scrolloff'` — “for new splits, if there's `<= 'lines'` of text in the buffer, then set `'winheight'` to `'lines' + N`”; but if that's not possible, a hotkey to achieve the same for the current window would probably suffice!

Comment: I don't have an exact solution, but I've used https://github.com/simeji/winresizer for a few years for interactive resizing with great success

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
:execute 'resize' line("$") + 5
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Manual approach

You can use `2<c-w>0` to resize current window to fit buffer, with `2` extra lines.

It's fully commented, read comment as explanation.

```
" Resize window to fit buffer + <count>. It works the same as <c-w>_ if there
" are too many lines to fit.
command -count WinFitBuf call s:win_fit_buf(<count>)
nnoremap <expr> <c-w>0 printf(':<c-u>%dWinFitBuf<cr>', v:count)

function s:win_fit_buf(extra_lines) abort

  " save old view
  let cview = winsaveview()

  try

    " I must find screen line count for current buffer, I don't know how to do
    " it directly, so I decide to maximize current window first, then shrink to
    " fit, I only need last screen line of current buffer this way.
    wincmd _

    " Clear scroll, goto last byte. I start this with ex 0 and $, but they don't
    " clear scroll until script finished.
    keepjump norm! ggG$

    " resize to fit
    exe printf('%dwincmd _',  winline() + a:extra_lines)

  finally

    " restore old view
    cal winrestview(cview)
  endtry

endfunction
```

---

#### Automatic

It's tricky to do it automatically:

- You can't do it with `WinNew`, as you don't know new buffer line count in
  this moment, the `<afile>` and `bufname()` all points to the old buffer
  name.
- You can't do it with `WinBufEnter`, as `:e file` will trigger it.
- You must also make sure new window is in a `col` layout.
- You must make sure it's not a blank buffer.

I didn't do it, it looks complicate and fragile.